# Dijkstra algorithm in python using dictionaries

Tags: python, dijkstra

Dear computer science enthusiasts,

I have stumbled upon an issue when trying to implement the *Dijkstra-algorithm* to determine the shortest path between a starting node and all other nodes in a graph.

To be precise I will provide you with as many code snippets and information as I consider useful to the case. However, should you miss anything, please let me know.

I implemented a **PQueue** class to handle Priority Queues of each individual node and it looks like this:

```
class PQueue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def push(self, u, value):
        self.items.append((u, value))

        # insertion sort
        j = len(self.items) - 1
        while j > 0 and self.items[j - 1][1] > value:
            self.items[j] = self.items[j - 1]  # Move element 1 position backwards
            j -= 1
        # node u now belongs to position j
        self.items[j] = (u, value)

    def decrease_key(self, u, value):
        for i in range(len(self.items)):
            if self.items[i][0] == u:
                self.items[i][1] = value
                j = i
                break

        # insertion sort
        while j > 0 and self.items[j - 1][1] > value:
            self.items[j] = self.items[j - 1]  # Move element 1 position backwards
            j -= 1
        # node u now belongs to position j
        self.items[j] = (u, value)

def pop_min(self):
    if len(self.items) == 0:
        return None
    self.items.__delitem__(0)
    return self.items.index(min(self.items))
```

In case you're not too sure about what the Dijkstra-algorithm is, you can [refresh your knowledge here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm).
Now to get to the actual problem, I declared a function dijkstra:

```
def dijkstra(self, start):
    # init
    totalCosts = {}  # {"node"= cost,...}
    prevNodes = {}  # {"node"= prevNode,...}
    minPQ = PQueue()  # [[node, cost],...]
    visited = set()

    # start init
    totalCosts[str(start)] = 0
    prevNodes[str(start)] = start
    minPQ.push(start, 0)

    # set for all other nodes cost to inf
    for node in range(self.graph.length):  # #nodes
        if node != start:
            totalCosts[str(node)] = np.inf

    while len(minPQ.items) != 0:  # Main loop
        # remove smallest item
        curr_node = minPQ.items[0][0]  # get index/number of curr_node
        minPQ.pop_min()
        visited.add(curr_node)

        # check neighbors
        for neighbor in self.graph.adj_list[curr_node]:
            # check if visited
            if neighbor not in visited:
                # check cost and put it in totalCost and update prev node
                cost = self.graph.val_edges[curr_node][neighbor]  # update cost of curr_node -> neighbor
                minPQ.push(neighbor, cost)
                totalCosts[str(neighbor)] = cost  # update cost
                prevNodes[str(neighbor)] = curr_node  # update prev

                # calc alternate path
                altpath = totalCosts[str(curr_node)] + self.graph.val_edges[curr_node][neighbor]
                # val_edges is a adj_matrix with values for the connecting edges

                if altpath < totalCosts[str(neighbor)]:  # check if new path is better
                    totalCosts[str(neighbor)] = altpath
                    prevNodes[str(neighbor)] = curr_node

                    minPQ.decrease_key(neighbor, altpath)
```

Which in my eyes should solve the problem mentioned above (optimal path for a starting node to every other node). But it does not. Can someone help me clean up this mess that I have been trying to debug for a while now. Thank you in advance!

**Assumption:**

In fact I realized that my dictionaries used to store the previously visited nodes (**prevNodes**) and the one where I save the corresponding total cost of visiting a node (**totalCosts**) **are unequally long**. And I do not understand why.

Comment: Are you doing this for learning/fun or do you only need an implementation of the algorithm? Because through Google you can find many implementations (in Python as well) already (some of which are hosted on GitHub).

Comment: Side note: the algorithm to determine the shortest path from a node to **all** other nodes is tje algorithm of Ford-Bellman. Not Dijkstra. Dijkstra only gives A->B